# Why would data.loading not become true during data.fetchMore?

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

Inside render:

```
  console.log('render', User.length, loading, networkStatus)
```

When I call `data.fetchMore` twice, I get:

```
render 100 false 7
render 200 false 7
render 300 false 7
```

Whereas I expect:

```
render 100 false 7
render 100 true 1
render 200 false 7
render 200 true 1
render 300 false 7
```

It works as expected (`loading` becomes true) in this example:

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/v3-beta/examples/with-apollo

But not in my code:

https://out-bkathectgx.now.sh/

https://github.com/lorensr/graphql-leaderboard/tree/a331af803b36ee2d65c85795d747e6cf4c83ba27

File:

https://github.com/lorensr/graphql-leaderboard/blob/a331af803b36ee2d65c85795d747e6cf4c83ba27/components/ReputationLeaderboard.js

[docs: data.networkStatus](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api-queries.html#graphql-query-data-networkStatus)

[docs: data.loading](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api-queries.html#graphql-query-data-loading)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was having the same problem. Turns out you have to opt in by setting `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange` to `true` in your options:

http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api-queries.html#graphql-config-options-notifyOnNetworkStatusChange

**P.S.** I had an additional problem of using old versions of `apollo-client` and `react-apollo` so I had to upgrade to the latest versions (at the time of writing `apollo-client@1.2.2` and `react-apollo@1.2.0`) so make sure you're on a latest enough version for these options to be available.